# Why I am getting program hang on the AcceptTcpClient?

Tags: c#

Why I am getting program hang on the `tcpClient = this.ss.AcceptTcpClient`?

---

```
public virtual void Run()
{
    if (this.tcpListener == null)
        return;

    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)null;

    while (!this.m_Stop)
    {
        try
        {
            tcpClient = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.handler.Handle), (object)tcpClient);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here `ss` is the `TcpListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I googled for [TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient%28v=vs.100%29). This is what I found.

> AcceptTcpClient is a blocking method that returns a TcpClient that you
>   can use to send and receive data. Use the Pending method to determine
>   if connection requests are available in the incoming connection queue
>   if you want to avoid blocking.

It seems that the method waits till there is a connection request available. So either use the Pending method call or do this on a background thread (not the UI thread).

Comment: But how can i use it give any example thanks in advance

Comment: try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending%28v=vs.100%29